# Como remover um elemento de estrutura

Tags: c

Estou com problema ao remover um elemento da lista.
Segue código feito:

```
#include<stdio.h>// colocar no esquininho do AVA ate amanha
#include<stdlib.h>
#define max 5
typedef struct info
{
    int numero;
    struct info* prox;
}Lista; //tipo de dado

Lista* inicializar()
{
    return NULL;
}
Lista* inserir(Lista* prim,int valor)
{
    Lista* novo;
    novo=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    novo->numero=valor;
    novo->prox=prim;

    return novo;
}
void Imprima(Lista* prim)
{
    while(prim!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n",prim->numero);
        prim=prim->prox;
    }
}


Lista* retira(Lista* recebida, int v)
{
    Lista* ant=NULL;
    Lista* p=recebida;
    while(p!=NULL && p->numero!=v)
    {
         ant=p;
         p=p->prox;
    }
    if(p==NULL)

          return recebida;

          if(ant==NULL)
          {
            recebida=p->prox;
          }
          else
          {
               ant->prox=p->prox;

          }
          free(p);
        return recebida;
}
main()
{
    Lista* prim;
    Lista* p;
    int valor,resp,i,num;

    prim=(struct info*)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    prim=inicializar();

    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        printf("\nDigite um valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&valor);
        prim=inserir(prim,valor);
        printf("\n\nGostaria de continuar 1 (sim) outro valor para nao: ");
        scanf("%d",&resp);

        if(resp!=1)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    Imprima(prim);
    printf("Escolha um numero que queira remover: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    prim=retira(prim,num);
    Imprima(p);
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: E porque nao te limitas a C++ e usas [`std::list`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29)?

Comment: C++ ou C ? São coisas muito diferentes.

Comment: da uma olhada nesse código https://github.com/brumazzi/pilha_stack/blob/master/stack.h

Answer (score 0):

O problema não é na remoção, mas sim na impressão da lista após remover.
Acho que você queria escrever:

```
p=retira(prim,num);
Imprima(p);
```

Mas ao invés disso está assim:

```
prim=retira(prim,num);
Imprima(p);
```

Então a lista sem o elemento retirado não está sendo impressa.

Answer (score 0):

Um bloco do seu codigo esta assim:

```
    Imprima(prim);
    printf("Escolha um numero que queira remover: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    prim = retira(prim, num);
    Imprima(p);
    system("pause");
```

O problema esta nesse ponteiro * p(Nao entendi o pq de ter criado esse ponteiro, n vi uso dele no codigo) trocando ele por * prim o problema é resolvido. Sera impresso antes e apos a exclusão normalmente:

```
    Imprima(prim);
    printf("Escolha um numero que queira remover: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    prim = retira(prim, num);
    Imprima(prim);
    system("pause");
```

Possivelmente estava dando erro pq o seu codigo estava tentando imprimir utilizando um ponteiro que nao foi inicializado.